# Сжатие картинки

Tags: сжатие, php, изображения

Суть вопроса в чем: я загружаю картинку на сервер, сохраняю ее например по адресу `$uploadfile='im/20130623134413_2266.jpg';` далее мне нужно уменьшить эту картинку, не сделать маленькую копию, а именно **уменьшить** оригинал.... 
Нашел вот такой код, но он почему-то не пашет:

```
$filename11 = $uploadfile;

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename11);
$new_width = 1024;
$new_height = 724;

$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename11);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

imagejpeg($image_p, 50); //50% это качество 0-100%
```

может кто-то подскажет почему не работает, или знает другое решение?!

Comment: Вам нужно "уменьшить" размер фото или размер файла?

Comment: в иделаи нужно уменьшить файл, так как файлы занимают по 2-5 мег, и расширение 2000-5000 пискселей (ширина), думал уменьшить картинку до 1024 (ширина), следовательно размер файла также уменьшется

Comment: Смотрите описание imagejpeg

Comment: imagejpeg выводит изображение, а мне именно нужно уменьшить его физичиский размер на сервере!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вспомнить описание функции imagejpeg, становится совершенно очевидно, что вы забыли указать имя файла.

```
imagejpeg($img,$filename,$quality);
```

Пусть оно будет таким же, как был оригинал. Тогда оригинал перезапишется.
Если вы не хотите каждый раз писать столько всего, создайте простенький класс (пример интерфейса):

```
interface ImageManager{
    function resize($newWidth,$newHeight);
    function saveAs($filename);
    function save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот эта статья тебе очень поможет http://www.php.su/articles/?cat=graph&page=017
Там про всё, про сжатие, про масштабирование. В общем всё, что поможет уменьшить вес изображения.